Wildfly Admin Page returning 403
I have default WildFly setup where management interface is listening on http instead of https. However I've changed port to be 8990. This is the config:
<management-interfaces>
            <http-interface http-authentication-factory="management-http-authentication">
                <http-upgrade enabled="true" sasl-authentication-factory="management-sasl-authentication"/>
                <socket-binding http="management-http"/>
            </http-interface>
</management-interfaces>

When using curl to reach management interface http://127.0.0.1:8990/management it's successful. I do need to use --digest and provide credentials to login.
However, I've configured traefik in front of wildfly, both management and web. Traefik entrypoint is listening to 9990:
mgmt:
  http2:
    maxConcurrentStreams: 250
  address: :9990
  transport:
    respondingTimeouts:
      readTimeout: 0

And this is configuration regarding management interface:
http:
  routers:
    router-mgmt-secure:
      rule: Host(`host.domain.com`)
      service: gateway-mgmt
      entryPoints:
      - mgmt
      middlewares:
      - hsts-header
      tls: {}
  middlewares:
    hsts-header:
      headers:
        browserXSSFilter: true
        contentTypeNosniff: true
        forceSTSHeader: true
        stsIncludeSubdomains: true
        stsSeconds: 63072000
        frameDeny: true
  services:
    gateway-mgmt:
      loadBalancer:
        serversTransport: insecureTransport
        servers:
        - url: http://127.0.0.1:8990/
        passHostHeader: true
  serversTransports:
    insecureTransport:
      insecureSkipVerify: true

When visiting WildFly admin page, i get prompted for credentials. I input them, they get accepted but i get a blank page.
When checking browser developer console, i see 403 on following urls:

https://host.domain.com:9990/management
https://host.domain.com:9990/console/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.b6d3c411.woff2
https://host.domain.com:9990/console/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.e5de314f.woff
https://host.domain.com:9990/console/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.8bd2b33b.ttf

However, if i change WildFly management interface to use ssl, like this:
<management-interfaces>
            <http-interface http-authentication-factory="management-http-authentication" ssl-context="applicationSSC">
                <http-upgrade enabled="true" sasl-authentication-factory="management-sasl-authentication"/>
                <socket-binding https="management-http"/>
            </http-interface>
</management-interfaces>

And change configuration in traefik to use https:// instead of http:// it works fine.
What would be the issue?
Traefik version: 3.1.0
WildFly version: 26.1.3
